# Simplest and Optimised way to read and edit YAMLs

Tags: docker, go, kubernetes, environment-variables, yaml

I've some YAML files which I wanted to apply to create Custom Resources. But before applying it I want to change the spec and ENVs of the YAML snippet. So what could be the best way to do this?

What I'm doing now is:

Let suppose this is the YAML

```yaml
apiVersion: litmuschaos.io/v1alpha1
kind: ChaosEngine
metadata:
  name: nginx-chaos
  namespace: default
spec:
  appinfo:
    appns: 'default'
    applabel: 'app=nginx'
    appkind: 'deployment'
  # It can be true/false
  annotationCheck: 'false'
  # It can be active/stop
  engineState: 'active'
  chaosServiceAccount: pod-delete-sa
  monitoring: false
  # It can be delete/retain
  jobCleanUpPolicy: 'delete'
  experiments:
    - name: pod-delete
      spec:
        components:
          env:
            # set chaos duration (in sec) as desired
            - name: TOTAL_CHAOS_DURATION
              value: '30'

            # set chaos interval (in sec) as desired
            - name: CHAOS_INTERVAL
              value: '10'
              
            # pod failures without '--force' & default terminationGracePeriodSeconds
            - name: FORCE
              value: 'false'
```

1. I Download this file from the raw link. (1 function for this)
2. Replace a field like `jobCleanUpPolicy: 'delete'` to `jobCleanUpPolicy: 'retain'` (1 fn)
3. Replace the next line when a match is found like `value: 'false'` to `value: 'true'` for FORCE ENV. (1 fn)
4. Applying the final manifest created! (1 function)

Can this be optimized?

Answer (score 4):

If you create a struct representing the resource (or, even better, can import the package which defines the CRD) you could take the yaml string, [marshal](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/yaml.v2#Marshaler) it into the struct and then edit the fields directly as fields of a struct instead

Answer (score 1):

Hi You may use LitmusPortal to use this.[Refer](https://github.com/litmuschaos/litmus)